Fixed position in the first column for the nodes, not in the others
I want a table of 2 columns with graphviz. Within the first columns I would like to have fixed positions for the nodes (x and Y). The other nodes can be freely positioned by graphviz within the assigned (other) column, i.e. the Y position does not matter. The positions within the first columns should not change, regardless of the connections to the nodes in the other columns
    digraph G {
      rankdir=LR;
      node [shape=box];
      
      subgraph cluster_0 {
        label = "Spalte 1";
        a [pos="0,2!"];
        b [pos="0,1!"];
        c [pos="0,0!"];
      }
    
      subgraph cluster_1 {
        label = "Spalte 2";
        d;
        e;
        f;
      }
    
  a-> e;
  a -> f;
    
    }

Currently the column slides up instead of the nodes within the column. Just change a-> to somethig to see it.

packmode (https://www.graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/packMode/) seems to accomplish your goal.
Note that nodes are in first-in-last-out order.
digraph G {
      rankdir=LR;
      packmode="array_ic2"  // the two clusters must not be connected (no edges)
      // packmode works best with recent (~2024 and later) releases of Graphviz
      node [shape=box];
      
      subgraph cluster_0 {
        label = "Spalte 1";
        a [pos="0,2!"];  // fyi, dot ignores all pos attributes
        b [pos="0,1!"];
        c [pos="0,0!"];
      }
    
      subgraph cluster_1 {
        label = "Spalte 2";
        d;
        e;
        f;
      }
    
// packmode requires no edges between the clusters to be "packed"
//  a-> e;  
//  a -> f;
    
    }

Giving:


I have just tried the latest version. When i connect one of the nodes, the column moves up. i want to connect the nodes, but the columns should stay that way. the nodes in the first column are fixed, the others should be aligned by graphviz itself... within the column and the columns next to each other at the same height
